# Automatic phonetic transcription of speech: is it still a difficult problem?

Tags: nlp, transcription

A friend was asking me why there aren't any programs that can analyze a user's pronunciation of words and then give feedback/suggestions.

Indeed, given an accurate phonetic transcription of a predetermined set of words, determining if a user's pronunciation of each word is standard/correct — or, say, determining someone's regional accent — should be trivial.

However, my sense was that Automatic Phonetic Transcription (APT) is not nearly accurate enough to analyze a user's pronunciation in that way — though my knowledge is about 10 years out of date.

Still, it made me wonder: even if APT of *spontaneous* speech does have a low accuracy — in a context where each expected word (and even possible alternate pronunciations) is known ahead of time, would accuracy conceivably high enough to give a user feedback on pronunciation?

Edit: arjan pointed out that Rosetta Stone claims to be able to give pronunciation feedback; how does such a system work (and how well)?

Comment: I don't know how accurate it is, but Rosetta Stone offers it in a commercial product, so it must have at least some merit. From their website: "Our exclusive speech-recognition software monitors your pronunciation – every syllable, word and sentence – and offers instant, feedback." ([link](http://www.rosettastone.eu/personal/how-it-works/speak-confidently)). A problem with this (promotion of a commercial product) may be a lack of published and verifiable findings - or are there?

Answer (score 5):

True automatic transcription is still nonexistent, unfortunately. The closest thing that I know of is this thing called Blitzscribe, which seems to be reasonably accurate (88–94%). This is what was/is used in the [Human Speechome Project](http://www.media.mit.edu/cogmac/projects/hsp.html), which is also very interesting.

Here are some sources for further reading: The [Study on the success of Blitzscribe](http://www.media.mit.edu/cogmac/publications/broy-interspeech2009.pdf) and [Ted Talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/deb_roy_the_birth_of_a_word.html) by Deb Roy, the guy who started the Human Speechome Project